# TypeError: can't pickle generator objects

Tags: python, generator, pickle

I am trying to write some result on to pickle file as below:

```
raw_X = (self.token_ques(text) for text in training_data)
with open('/root/Desktop/classifier_result.pkl', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(raw_X, handle)
```

Error:

```
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle generator objects
```

Any help would be much appreciable.

Comment: This is an old issue:  http://bugs.python.org/issue1092962, however stackless python has solved it: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/198963.  It *is* possible, but you have to work in python at the C/C++ level.

Comment: Interestingly, the reasons given here: http://peadrop.com/blog/2009/12/29/why-you-cannot-pickle-generators/ are handled by `stackless`… and also for the most part by `dill`.

Answer (score 11):

Don't use a generator expression when you want to pickle data. Use a list comprehension instead, or call `list()` on the generator to capture all generated elements for pickling.

For example, the following works just fine:

```
raw_X = [self.token_ques(text) for text in training_data]
with open('/root/Desktop/classifier_result.pkl', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(raw_X, handle)
```

as does:

```
raw_X = (self.token_ques(text) for text in training_data)
with open('/root/Desktop/classifier_result.pkl', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(list(raw_X), handle)
```

Comment: @nlper: so what does `self.token_ques(text)` return? Is that a generator object too perhaps?

Comment: yeah, when I printed type it gave `<type 'generator'>
`

Comment: So apply `list()` to each return value; `raw_X = [list(self.token_ques(text)) for text in training_data]`

Comment: okay, but when I load it back, how can I put it in original form

Comment: Define *original form*. You can still iterate over the unpickled lists; they are iterables just like the generators produced iterables.

Comment: You cannot make them into generators anymore; at best you can produce iterators for each  with `(iter(tokens) for tokens in unpickled_list)`; that's a generator expression containing iterables (can be looped over just once).

Answer (score 5):

```
raw_X = (self.token_ques(text) for text in training_data)
```

This is a generator. As the error says, we cannot pickle generators. Use this instead.

```
raw_X=[]
for text in data:
  raw_X.append(self.token_ques(text))
raw_X=tuple(raw_X)
```

And pickle `raw_X` then.

---

**Edit**

This works for me

```
import pickle

raw_X=[]
data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,2,0]
for text in data:
    raw_X.append(str(text))

print pickle.dumps(raw_X)
```

I'm using `str()` instead of your function and `dumps()` instead of `dump()`.

Comment: Why turning it into a tuple? If a tuple was the goal, just use `tuple(self.token_ques(text) for text in training_data)`.

Comment: Using `append` is much slower than list comprehension.