# pickling networkx graph: can't pickle generator objects

Tags: networkx, pickle

I am trying to pickle my networkx graph but getting the next error

```
can't pickle generator objects
```

I read [TypeError: can't pickle generator objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963354/typeerror-cant-pickle-generator-objects/28963385#28963385) that you can't pickle generator. how can I find where is my generator in the graph object ? is there a way to traverse recursively on object and find type == generator ?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: I build a graph, and in a lot of places I add/remove objects/edges... so I can't show the whole project... what I looking for is how can I debug this ?

Comment: This is going to be tough to help you with.  I've never seen this error when pickling networkx graphs.  So without more detail, I think we can't really tell you how to find the generator.   Can you at least provide the call to pickle?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with networkx version on Python 2.x, stemming from the change in networkx functions (e.g., for calculating shortest path lengths) that return a generator in the recent versions of the package as opposed to a dictionary in the 1.x versions.

A workaround would be checking whether the object returned by networkx is a generator and if it is, converting it to picklable object, for example the following code was tested using Python 2.7.16 and networkx 2.2:

```
import networkx, types, cPickle
G = networkx.cycle_graph(5)
val = networkx.shortest_path_length(G)
if isinstance(val, types.GeneratorType): # newer versions of networkx returns generator
    val_new = {source: target_dict for source, target_dict in val}
    val = val_new
cPickle.dump(val, open("test.pkl", 'w'))
```