# Fit generator with yield generator. Cannot Pickle 'generator' object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following code:

```
def generator_train(x_train_df, y_train_df, batch_size):
    for i in range(int(len(x_train_df) / batch_size)):
        x_train = x_train_df[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size]
        y_train = y_train_df[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size]

        yield np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

train_generator = generator_train(x_train_df, y_train_df, batch_size)

history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    epochs=epochs_no,
                    steps_per_epoch=number_of_rows_input/batch_size,
                    verbose=1,
                    max_queue_size=100,
                    validation_data=None,
                    workers=8,
                    use_multiprocessing=True
                    )
```

The `x_train_df`, `y_train_df` are `pandas.DataFrame` both.
I'm still getting the following error referring to pickle. However, the fit_generator should have noting to do with dumping/loading pickled data.

```py
Exception in thread Traceback (most recent call last):

Thread-2  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\Tut\pythonProject5_MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 868, in _run
    with closing(self.executor_fn(_SHARED_SEQUENCES)) as executor:
  File "E:\Tut\pythonProject5_MachineLearning\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 858, in pool_fn
    pool = get_pool_class(True)(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 212, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 303, in _repopulate_pool
    return self._repopulate_pool_static(self._ctx, self.Process,
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 326, in _repopulate_pool_static
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump

    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)

TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: can't pickle generator objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963354/typeerror-cant-pickle-generator-objects)

Comment: You can't pickle a generator, as it says.  Since you have `use_multiprocessing=True`, it has to pickle everything you send it to the new processes.  There is no way around this (in standard python) except not using a generator.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be by using MirroredStrategy() for the neural network and the date should be preprocessed using the functions from tensorflow.data.Dataset

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with strategy.scope():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense.....
    .....
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='sgd')


def dataset_fn(dummy_argument):
    x = np.array(x_train_df).astype(np.float32)
    y = np.array(y_train_df).astype(np.float32)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))

    return dataset.repeat().batch(batch_size=batch_size, drop_remainder=True)

dist_dataset = strategy.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function(dataset_fn)

history = model.fit(
    dist_dataset,
    epochs=epochs,
    steps_per_epoch=number_of_batches_in_the_x_set,
    verbose=1,
    max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    validation_data=None,
    workers=number_of_workers,
    use_multiprocessing=True
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You *are* pickling: because you're using multiprocessing, and multiprocessing needs to pickle anything it runs to send it to the new python processes.  Since your `train_generator` is needed in each process, it will be sent, i.e. pickled.

As the linked question notes, avoid this by not using a generator: trivially, cast to list and evaluate before sending; but more sensibly, rewrite your generator to return the list for you.